# Keep resizing text from pushing the other elements in its container around?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have the following html

```
          <div id="menu">
            <ul class="horizMenu">
            <li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

and in the css I have

```
.horizMenu li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
#menu
{


    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    letter-spacing:7px;
}
#menu a
{
    color:red;

}
#menu a:hover
{
    color:blue;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Everything works pretty well, except that when I mouse over the links, the color changes and it becomes bold, which is what i want, but it also causes all of the other li elements to move slightly and then move back when you mouse-off. Is there an easy way to stop this from happening?

Comment: not sure why i got a minus 1 but if you fix the width of the li element then bolding the hrefs wont have the same effect as there is enough room in the li to accomodate the new width.  I use this .Net xhtml all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure who -1ed, but Mauro's answer is essentially correct: you can't trivially make an item with automatic width depend on what the width would have been if the font inside weren't bold.

However, a 'float: left;' rule will also be necessary as you can't set the width of an inline-display element. And 'em' would probably be a better unit, to make the required width dependent on the font size in the buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Add a width to the list item elements which is bigger than the bolded width of the items, this way they wont be pushed out of line.

```
#menu li
{
   width: 150px;
}
```

Alternatively you could try a monospace font, which wont be affected by the bold/unbold on hover.

Answer (score 1):

try using this
menutext {
line-height: 10px; /* or whatever */
}

and also, to set the width of a inline element, use display: inline-block;

float:left might be not so friendly, if you do use it and it messes things up use clear:both

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem. A solution I thought of, and might use from now on, is to use text-shadow instead.

```
a:hover {
  color:blue;
  text-shadow:0px 0px 1px blue;
}
```

The text will look a little blur though. If you set the 3rd parameter to 0, text won't be blur but will look just a little bit bolder.

I'd say this is better than dealing with width-dynamic texts.